# Inline code when counting data items (using templates)

Tags: c++, templates

There is a simple POD data type like

```
struct Item {
   int value1;
   double value2;
   bool value3;
}
```

Now I would like to write different count functions like it could be done with the following code (or some std method):

```
typedef bool Selector(const Item& i);
int count(const vector<Item>& items, Selector f) {
  int sum = 0;
  BOOST_FOREACH(const Item& i, items) {
    if(f(i)) {
      sum++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

with `f` e.g.

```
bool someSimpleSelector(const Item& i) {
  return i.value1 > 0; // quite simple criterion
}
```

However in this approach the compiler can not inline the function call and thus will not inline my (trivial) selection code.

My question would be: is there a possibility to implement the above code in a way, where the compiler can inline my selection code, but without implementing the whole count function again and again explicitely (for example by using templates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `typedef` with a template parameter, to allow generic functors:

```
template <typename Selector>
int count(const vector<Item>& items, const Selector &f)
```

Then replace your functions with function objects:

```
struct someSimpleSelector
{
    bool operator()(const Item& i) const { return i.value1 > 0; }
};
```

You should find that this gets inlined, with suitable compiler optimisation settings.

By the way, this particular problem can be solved using `std::count_if()`.

Answer (score 2):

See the new boost range adaptors

```
Selector f;
int count = std::distance(items | boost::range::adaptor::filtered(f));
```

For more details read on.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html

Comment: Does this create a new sequence or is it implemented lazy?

Comment: The range adapters are totally lazy and they compose very nicely. I now use them exclusively for range processing algorithms. The one other element of the toolkit not provided by boost is polymorphic iterators / ranges. Read here if you are curious. http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Comment: This looks interesting and is probably worth getting into it. But for now I choosed the simpler approach in the other answer.

Comment: Actually *most* of the time you can avoid creating struct type functions and just use normal C functions together with boost::bind. Or if you are brave enough to use c++0x features in GCC you can use lambdas.

std::distance(items | filtered( [&](const Item & i){ i.value1 > 0; } ))

 Then you will almost be able to program C++ like Ruby!